# How to Deserializie multiple Json files and and pass the data into multiple objects

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I am currently creating selenium c# automation framework using Dependency Injection. Currently I want to read and deserializie all the Json files in project and then pass the values in to objects which are located in separate classes.I have manged to do it for one file, but I am having a hard time achiving the same to multiple files.

**WebDriverInitializerExtension.cs**

```
public static class WebDriverInitializerExtension
{
    public static IServiceCollection UseWebDriverInitializer(
        this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton(ReadConfig());

        return services;
    }

    private static AppSettings ReadConfig()
    {
        var configFile = File
                        .ReadAllText(Path.GetDirectoryName(
                            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
                        + "/Settings/appsettings.json");

    

        var appSettings = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AppSettings>(configFile);

        return appSettings;

    }

}
```

**AppSettings.cs**

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public string? BrowserType { get; set; }

    public string? URL { get; set; }

    public string? HeadlessMode { get; set; }


}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{

  "BrowserType": "Chrome",
  
  "URL": "https://release.demo.bnz.co.nz/client/",

  "HeadlessMode": "false"
}
```

now using the above code I can get all the data from the appsettings.json file and deserilize it and then pass them to app settings class. I want to achive the same thing for multiple Json files and pass them to separate objects which are located in separate classes.
Bsically I want to:

1. read all the Json files in the project and deserialize them
2. Pass those values into objects which are located in separate classes.

Comment: this is not selenium/automation related

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on whether you care about being able to differentiate between the different files. Because in that case I'd suggest creating a separate class for each file.

If not then you could just dependency inject each file. In this case I assume that a filename is passed to ReadConfig.

```cs
services.AddScoped(ReadConfig("appsettings1.json"));
services.AddScoped(ReadConfig("appsettings2.json"));
return services;
```

This effectively injects the class AppSettings multiple times. Which is fine.
Because we can still use it whatever services like so:

```cs
public class SomeService
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<AppSettings> allAppSettings;
    public SomeService(IEnumerable<AppSettings> allAppSettings)
    {
        this.allAppSettings = allAppSettings;
        foreach(var appSettings in allAppSettings)
        {
            // assign objects and do whatever
        }
    }
}
```